# jQuery split array problems

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, list, split

i had try to make a split with jQuery on a array field but it dosen't work :

```
var arr;
arr[0] = 'size:256';
var vals = $(arr[0]).split(':');
alert(vals);​
```

Why ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you think that jQuery provides any such `.split()` method? [It does not](http://api.jquery.com/split).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need in jQuery, just pure JavaScript. String [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is native JS function.

```
var arr = [];     // and don't forget to initialize array
arr[0] = 'size:256';

var vals = arr[0].split(':');
alert(vals[0]);   // gives "size"
alert(vals[1]);   // gives "256"
```

Comment: The OP also needs to initialize `var arr = []`.

Comment: thanks guys it work ! But i can accept your awnser after 11 minutes